# High Read an Write Latency in cassandra 2.2.6

Tags: cassandra, latency

Hi similar question was already asked but I guess we have a bit different problem:

We use Cassandra 2.2.6 one node installation (and going to upgrade to the newest). Right now we've got horrible time of queries and sometimes write timeouts.

```
    Read Count: 21554802
    Read Latency: 10.702975718589295 ms.
    Write Count: 19437551
    Write Latency: 27.806026818707767 ms.
    Pending Flushes: 0
            Table: -----
            SSTable count: 5
            Space used (live): 661310370
            Space used (total): 661310370
            Space used by snapshots (total): 704698632
            Off heap memory used (total): 845494
            SSTable Compression Ratio: 0.13491738106721324
            Number of keys (estimate): 179623
            Memtable cell count: 594836
            Memtable data size: 8816212
            Memtable off heap memory used: 0
            Memtable switch count: 3343
            Local read count: 21554802
            Local read latency: 11,744 ms
            Local write count: 19437551
            Local write latency: 30,506 ms
            Pending flushes: 0
            Bloom filter false positives: 387
            Bloom filter false ratio: 0,00024
            Bloom filter space used: 258368
            Bloom filter off heap memory used: 258328
            Index summary off heap memory used: 34830
            Compression metadata off heap memory used: 552336
            Compacted partition minimum bytes: 180
            Compacted partition maximum bytes: 12108970
            Compacted partition mean bytes: 23949
            Average live cells per slice (last five minutes): 906.8858219156                                                       92
            Maximum live cells per slice (last five minutes): 182785
            Average tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 1.432102507830                                                       9697
            Maximum tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 50
```

For comparison, there is a different table containing about 10M records and constructed quite similar to the above

```
    Read Count: 815780599
    Read Latency: 0.1672932019580917 ms.
    Write Count: 3083462
    Write Latency: 1.5470194706469547 ms.
    Pending Flushes: 0
            Table: ------
            SSTable count: 9
            Space used (live): 5067447115
            Space used (total): 5067447115
            Space used by snapshots (total): 31810631860
            Off heap memory used (total): 19603932
            SSTable Compression Ratio: 0.2952622065160448
            Number of keys (estimate): 12020796
            Memtable cell count: 300611
            Memtable data size: 18020553
            Memtable off heap memory used: 0
            Memtable switch count: 97
            Local read count: 815780599
            Local read latency: 0,184 ms
            Local write count: 3083462
            Local write latency: 1,692 ms
            Pending flushes: 0
            Bloom filter false positives: 7
            Bloom filter false ratio: 0,00000
            Bloom filter space used: 15103552
            Bloom filter off heap memory used: 15103480
            Index summary off heap memory used: 2631412
            Compression metadata off heap memory used: 1869040
            Compacted partition minimum bytes: 925
            Compacted partition maximum bytes: 1916
            Compacted partition mean bytes: 1438
            Average live cells per slice (last five minutes): 1.0
            Maximum live cells per slice (last five minutes): 1
            Average tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 1.0193396020053622
            Maximum tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 3
```

Difference is the first one contains lots of maps and UDT. Simple test in dev center select * from ... limit 999; (omitting any Lucene indexes etc.) shows 183ms for the last one and 1.8s for the first one.

Anybody could help define a way to find the rootcause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Maximum live cells per slice (last five minutes): 182785

That is huge, probably from your maps and UDTs. Your data model is most likely the root cause. Walking live 180k cells to satisfy a single query will be very slow.

> select * from ... limit 999;

Range queries are inherently slow. Try to design your tables such that you can answer your question from a single partition and you will get better results.

> one node installation

Whenever there is a GC you will have a bad query, this is mitigated a by adding more nodes such that pauses wont hurt as bad (even better if use client side speculative retry on driver).

Comment: Thanks a lot. So comparing my results from the two mentioned tables I guess it leads to the first answer you proposed. But does this concern raw record size or in particular usage of the UDTs or map? As I think over now this way there is in fact one column, containing large list and not used anymore and the obsolate data was cleared yet. Will try to clear and check again.

Comment: I'm your fan :) basically 70% of the problem solved in 20min. :) (droped the  column with huge obsolate list)

Comment: Is there possible to make some additional performance boost by upgrading to Cassandra 3.x in the case?

Comment: I dont think 3.0 it would be significant one way or other, more likely it would be slightly slower.